# Как сделать в Electron окно поверх всех остальных окон как индикатор скайпа

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, electron

Привет, всем! Помогите сделать такое же окно, как и в скайпе через Electron. Смысл в том, что это окно находиться всегда поверх всех окон компьютера, включая игры.

Параметр alwaysOnTop: true ставит окно перед всеми другими окнами, но в игра в полноэкранном режиме покрывает его.

Подскажите, возможно ли и как это можно реализовать в Electron или какими способами это можно сделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]